# Javascript login redirect not working

Tags: javascript, button, if-statement, authentication, document.write

So, for my webdesign class I was asked by my teacher to teach the class simple javascript, and I wanted to make a simple website that either my teacher or I could use to do this. I wanted it to be something that (I thought would be simple) that had a login box, and when you logged in, if you used either my login or my teacher's login in it would work, and it would either create the buttons or redirect to another page that had the buttons on them, but for some reason the if else statement I am using for the login(since it there are only two instances in which it would be true is not wanting to work.

**Edit:** I am still learning Javascript and only understand enough of it to teach some of the very basic parts of it. (which is all that I need to atm) All I am trying to do is make the buttons appear so that I can then use them to call the functions that create the information that is written out when they are clicked. So for example, to create the buttons when the correct login information is given and then when the buttons that appear show up, you could click the first one and the paragraph about the script tag would appear.

**There is not much trouble with the password and name check functions working, when I make them both alerts, the first being eeyup if it is right and nnope if the info given is wrong, both of them work. It is only when I try to use document.write that I run into issues**

**At the moment, what it does is the buttons flash up on the screen for a split second then disappears and the login boxes/screen reappears. **

The login function I am using is:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
function validator(){
    var name = document.KageForm.User.value;
    var password= document.KageForm.pass.value;
    if(password=="mypassword" && name=="myusername"|| password=="myteacherspassword" &&name=="myteachersname" ){
  document.write(showbuttons());
} else {
    document.write("This is not meant for you to see.");
}}
</script>
```

The function to show the buttons, showbuttons, looks like this:

```
function showbuttons(){
    document.write("<div><form><input type=\"button\" value=\"Starting Your Script\" onclick=\"FirstThingsFirst()\"/><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Learn about document.write\" onclick=\"writing()\" /><br/><input  type=\"button\" value=\"Variables\"onclick=\"settingVariables()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Using Functions\" onclick=\"usingFunctions()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"If Statements\" onclick=\"usingIfStatements()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Else Statements\" onclick=\"usingElseStatements()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Login\" onclick=\"homepage()\" /></form></div>")
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}
```

The total code for the whole page is this: (Also if there are any inaccuracies in the text that the buttons pull up, please point them out)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>

            <style type="text/css"> 

      body {background-image:url(https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg)}
body{
    font-family:helvetica;
    color:darkviolet;
}
    h2 {color:darkviolet;}
    #tag1 {width:480px;}
#wrapper { width:960px;margin:0 auto; }
}

    div {
    margin: 5px;
      border: 5px solid darkviolet;
width:50%;

}
  img {
    width:20.00%;
    height:20.00%;

   }
ul li a {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #f2a7c6;
    float: left;
    border: 2px ;
}

a:link {text-decoration:none
    color:darkviolet;}
    h3 {
        font-family:helvetica;
    color:darkviolet
    }
   #white {
    color:white;
   }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">


/*<input type=\"button\" value=\"Starting Your Script\" onclick=\"FirstThingsFirst()\"/><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Learn about document.write\" onclick=\"writing()\" /><br/><input  type=\"button\" value=\"variables\"onclick=\"settingVariables()\" /><br/>input type=\"button\" value=\"Using Functions\" onclick=\"usingFunctions()\" /><br/>input type=\"button\" value=\"If Statements\" onclick=\"usingIfStatements()\" /><br/>input type=\"button\" value=\"Else Statements\" onclick=\"usingElseStatements()\" />*/

function FirstThingsFirst() {
var mytext = "<div id=\"thisshouldbewhite\"> To start writing Javascript into your page, you must first make use of the script tag. The tag is 'script' type=\"text/javascript\"  with the closing tag simply being /script. you can use a Javascript either in your heading of your page, after the style tag, or anywhere in your body. Personally, I prefer to put all my script, or at least my functions,  in the head of my page.</div> <input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Home\" onclick=\"homepage()\" />"
    document.write(mytext);
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}


function writing() 
{    
var mytext = "<div id=\"thisshouldbewhite\">To write something out on your screen, you use the command \'document.write()'. To get what you want to appear, put qutation marks around it in the paranthesis. So to write out \"bacon\", you would put: document.write(\"bacon\") in your script. Document.write() is used for many things, mainly displaying information based on input data given to the page by the user that fits into variables defined by the creator of the page. For example, document.write(variableX()) would print out anything that has been put in for variableX.</div><input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Home\" onclick=\"homepage()\" />"
    document.write(mytext);
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";

}
function settingVariables(){
    document.write("<div id=\"thisshouldbewhite\">to create a variable, youtype in \'var\' followed by a space, then the name of the variable, an = then what the variable is equal to. So, if you had food on your mind and wanted your variable to be \'bacon\' your variable would be: var food=\"bacon\"</div><input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Home\" onclick=\"homepage()\" />")
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}

function usingFunctions(){
  document.write("<div id=\"thisshouldbewhite\">Functions are used to use commands only when triggered, or to do multiple things at once. for example, open up a website and type in the following code: <br/> <i>function troll(){<br/>document.write(\"gotcha!\");<br/>document.write(gotcha());<br/> function gotcha(){<br/>document.write(\" hahahaha!\");<br/>document.write(troll())</i>;<br/> What this will do is that the first function will call the second function, and then when the second function is called it will call the first function.Since neither are being called at the moment, create a button in your html as usual, but in the starting tag, add the property\"onClick\". Name your button something like, 'start trolling' or something like that. So, your code for your input should look something like <i><-input type=\"button\" value=\"Starting Your Script\" onclick=\"FirstThingsFirst()\"/></i> <br/> obviously minus the dash at the start of the tag.</br><input type=\"button\" value=\"Commence Trolling\" onclick=\"troll()\"/></div><input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Home\" onclick=\"homepage()\" />");
  document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}
function usingIfStatements(){
  document.write("<div id=\"thisshouldbewhite\">If statements are used to create scenarios such as login screens, since that is the use that will be most familiar to most of us. An If statement goes inside the function tag, so when in use the statement looks like this:<br/>function login(){<br/>if(conditions for if statement){commands for if statement to follow}}<br/> Here is an example of a functional function using an IF Statement:<br/>function login(){<br/>var name=\"your name\";<br/>if(name==\"your name\"){document.write(\"You are indeed yourself\")}}<br/>This would print out the words in the command following the If statement, since the statement is true, since the variable, \"name\" is equal to \"your name\"</div><input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Home\" onclick=\"homepage()\" />");
  document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}

function usingElseStatements(){
    document.write("<div id=\"thisshouldbewhite\">So, we know how to make an If statement, now we are going to use Else statements. This would be like on a login screen, if you type in inaccurate information and it gives you an error message<i><br/>function login(){<br/>if(conditions for if statement){commands for if statement to follow}else(commands for script to follow if your If statement is not true)}</i><br/> Here is an example of a functional function using an IF Statement:<i><br/>function login(){<br/>var name=\"your name\";<br/>if(name==\"your name\"){document.write(\"You are indeed yourself\")else{document.write(\"you are not yourself when you're hungry.\")}}}<br/></i></div>")
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}


function troll(){
document.write("gotcha!");
document.write(gotcha());
}
function gotcha(){
document.write(" hahahaha!");
document.write(troll())
}

function homepage() 
{
    window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Websites/TEst.html";
}
function gotoButtons() 
{
    window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Websites/Buttons.html";
}


function showbuttons(){
    document.write("<div><form><input type=\"button\" value=\"Starting Your Script\" onclick=\"FirstThingsFirst()\"/><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Learn about document.write\" onclick=\"writing()\" /><br/><input  type=\"button\" value=\"Variables\"onclick=\"settingVariables()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Using Functions\" onclick=\"usingFunctions()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"If Statements\" onclick=\"usingIfStatements()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Else Statements\" onclick=\"usingElseStatements()\" /><br/><input type=\"button\" value=\"Return to Login\" onclick=\"homepage()\" /></form></div>")
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('https://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/029/6/8/smoke_by_kage_kaldaka-d5t50d9.jpg')";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.color="white";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.width="400px";
document.getElementById('thisshouldbewhite').style.fontFamily="helvetica";
}
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
           <script type="text/javascript">
      function validator(){
        var name = document.KageForm.User.value;
        var password= document.KageForm.pass.value;
        if(password=="mypassword" && name=="myusername"|| password=="myteacherspassword" &&name=="myteachersname" ){
      document.write(showbuttons());
    } else {
        document.write("This is not meant for you to see.");
    }}
        </script>
        <form name="KageForm">
            Username:<input type="text" name="User">
        <br/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
        <br/>
        <input type="image" src="https://a.deviantart.net/avatars/k/a/kage-kaldaka.png?6" 
         value="Submit" onclick="validator()" />
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Starting Your Script" onclick="FirstThingsFirst()"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Learn about document.write" onclick="writing()" />
        <br/>
        <input  type="button" value="Variables" 
       onclick="settingVariables()" />
         <br/>
       <input type="button" value="Using Functions" onclick="usingFunctions()" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" value="If Statements" onclick="usingIfStatements()" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" value="Else Statements" onclick="usingElseStatements()" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" value="" onclick="" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" value="" onclick="()" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" value="" onclick="()" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" value="" onclick="()" />


        </form>



    </body>



    </html>
```

Comment: Make sure you have some sort of hashing for the password and compare the hashes. I.e. store the hash of the password, and hash the password when it is entered. Then compare. Never transmit a password in cleartext, and especially not when you are using a client side script that students could mess with.

Comment: really shouldn't be JS's responsibility to authenticate credentials.... are you operating in an intranet sandbox? is the intent to illustrate exploits?

Comment: Chris, could you elaborate more on what that means? I am still learning Javascript as well, I just know enough to teach (very) basic things in it. I have not learned about hashes yet. The password to be honest, at this point, is not a major concern, because 1 I doubt that the people in my class would be able to find a way to mess with it since they always screw around and rarely know what to do as it is, and 2, it is just something I wanted to do on there. My main concern is getting the buttons to appear when the correct login information is given. Anything you can suggest about that?

Comment: Brandt, no idea what you just said. I added a further explanation of what I am trying to get done at the top of my post if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. Change `document.write(showbuttons());` to `showbuttons();` in your `validator()` function. Since `showbuttons()` does not return a string, but writes HTML itself;
2. Change

   `<input type="image" src="https://a.deviantart.net/avatars/k/a/kage-kaldaka.png?6" value="Submit" onclick="validator()" />`

   to

   `<img src="https://a.deviantart.net/avatars/k/a/kage-kaldaka.png?6" value="Submit" onclick="validator()" />`.

   Since `<input type="image" ... />` triggers browser to submit form and reload the page.

Working example you can see here http://jsbin.com/ayovom/2/edit.

Comment: Oh...hrm...now I am running into an issue with the buttons that write the information  not following the formatting that I put them in within the command, such as the text not staying white after the first button is clicked, but other than that it is working, and I think that is something that I can work around/find alternative options.

Comment: @KageKaldaka This happens because all your buttons have the same `id` which should be unique by definition. Instead of it you can either give different `id`s to your buttons or use `class="thisshouldbewhite"` with css `.thisshouldbewhite { clolor:white; width:400px; font-family:Helvetica;}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to put each condition in its own parenthesis

```
  (((password =="mypassword") && (name=="myusername")) || ((password=="myteacherspassword") && (name=="myteachersname")) )
```

so we put in parenthisis... before every & symbol as its own grouping.. both conditions before the or as one grouping and the other side the same

so you will have a total of six groupings.

also, if you plan on using this site, I once asked a "homework" or school related question and was crucified because it is apparently not allowed.

Comment: Well I have asked a homework/classwork related question once before and only got helpful feedback, so maybe you just had bad luck that day. I will try that and report whether or not it works.

Comment: sure thing. yeah haha.. maybe.. it was a sql thing and DBA's are a pain in the bleep

Comment: From sql on, that was all german to me until you got to pain in the bleep. Also, I tried that and I have the same issue, the buttons pop up for like an 8th of a second and then disappear.